# How to disable middleware only for specific function in controller if user pass data from a specific route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, url, laravel-middleware

**Requirement**

If data were passed into the function via a specific route then middleware authentication to be escaped only for a specific functions.

**What I have tried**

So I know I can use below method to escape middleware authentication for a specific function I want
But when I do this it will ignore authentication for spec_add function from all routes.

```
  public function __construct ()
    {
        $this -> middleware ( 'auth'  ,['except' => ['spec_add']]) ;
    }
```

I know I can implement something like below. But what I wants to know that is there is a better way to do this rather than below method.

```
public function __construct ()
{
    if (  url () -> previous () == 'special_url'){
        $this -> middleware ( MiddlewareConstants::Auth . ':' . GuardConstants::Customers  ,['except' => ['addAddress']]) ;
    }else{
        $this -> middleware ( MiddlewareConstants::Auth . ':' . GuardConstants::Customers  ) ;

    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your `web.php` give this a shot

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth',], function () {
   // all the routes here will have to go through auth
});

// this will not
Route::get('spec_add', 'TestController@function');
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank but when I use construct in controller this won't work . right.

Answer (score 2):

Since Laravel 7.7 you can use method `withoutMiddleware` eg:

```php
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->withoutMiddleware(['auth']);
```